# svn rm local file

Tags: svn

When I was create the first repository, in the client, I used `svn add *`
then I typed `svn del *`. unfortunately, I delete the file at my local mechine.
How can I restore these file?

Comment: Because I haven't commit any version to the repository, so, 'svn revert' does nothing!

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't commit it yet you can do *checkout* from repository.

Comment: I didn't commit it, but these files disappear. And the repository don't have these files.

Comment: Wait a minute. If you haven't commit you should just delete files locally. If something changed on repository that means, you commited changes.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really didn't change the repository or commited changes. I add the all files ,the rm the files.Then, they disappeared

Comment: Two questions:
1. Have you did it from terminal or b using some svn tool?
2. How do you checking, that files are deleted on repository?

If there are deleted at current commit you can always revert to some earlier revision (I don't remember now hot to do it from terminal, you have to google it)

Comment: why not 'svn revert'?? 0_0

Comment: @bahrep Ok, you are right, maybe post it as answer, so it can be accepted

Comment: Two answer:1.I did it from terminal. 2. the version in repository is 0, I haven't commit any. Also, 'svn revert' must be the case that the file is in the repository, so the method does nothing.

Comment: So you deleted files, that never was in repository. I don't think you can restore them using svn.